# Run write sql queries with caution in DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

Is there any flag in DataGrip that enables showing caution message of running **write** SQL queries(*UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE*). E.g. saying that

Reason: it's so easy to run queries in DataGrip with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and not paying attention what query you are running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent changes from being immediately committed to your DB, you can turn off "Auto-Commit" by connection/console.

This can be turned off from the toolbar, as shown in the image below, or in the bottom right of the connection properties window. From the properties window there is also a checkbox for "Read Only" if you are only pulling data.

[image: Data Grip Auto-commit check box position]

There is a tab on the bottom for "Database Changes" that tracks changes and must be reviewed prior to force committing the changes back to the source DB.

Answer (score 0):

In DataGrip 2017.3 *IDE-level read-only mode* was introduced. It can be turned on in the data source properties.

[image]

In read-only mode every DDL or DML query will be underlined.

[image]

If you execute it, there will be a warning. Anyway, it is possible to press Execute on this bar if you’re totally confident in what you are doing.

[image]

If a function executes another function (repeat n times) which executes DDL or DML statements, you’ll also see the warning.

[image]